# jquery value not updating on continous hover attempts

Tags: jquery

I got a hover effect which should alert the value of that divs `name="address"`. I got multiply divs with the class Display. But they each have their unique id. Below is what I got so far, but it aren't working. Any help is appreciated!

**JS**

```
$(".Display").hover(function(){
    alert($(this.id).find("[name='address']").val());
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="Display" id="someid">
    <input type="hidden" name="address" value="somevalue">  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like this

```
$(this).find("input[name='address']").val()
```

**SNIPPET**

```js
$(".Display").hover(function(){
    alert($(this).find("input[name='address']").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Display" id="someid">
    <input type="hidden" name="address" value="somevalue">  
  Jam
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked! Don't know why any downvoted ur answer

Comment: @JonCode you are welcome :)  some people become crazy after getting the power of downvote :P

Answer (score 0):

Fo what you are trying to do you need the `#` in the selector before the id:

```
$('#' + this.id).find("[name='address']").val()
```

However, there is no point in using the id to find the element when you already have a reference to the element:

```
$(this).find("[name='address']").val()
```

You don't even have to create a jQuery object from the element, you can use it as scope when you find the input:

```
$("[name='address']", this).val()
```